# Kivy error - Unable to find any valuable Window provider

Tags: python, error-handling, compiler-errors, kivy, kivymd

This is my code

'''

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
class Audibuddy(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text = "Does this work")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Audibuddy().run()
```

'''
When i try to run this i get the following error:

CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _window_sdl2: The specified module could not be found.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LcCx.png

I am using pycharm,I tried to run the same code in vscode and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried this code and it does work, your kivy installation might be faulty. Did you install kivy on the pycharm settings?